# postgres SQL query throws error in node JS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, pgrouting

I set up an API where on client side user can calculate a route between to points. However, I have trouble with the psql query, which works in postgres but when I use the same query in node JS I got an error.

I am using nodeJS, Express and Postgres. If I run the query below in pgAdmin4, I get the expected output.

```
SELECT b.gid, b.the_geom, b.cost_s, b.length_m FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid::bigint as id, source::bigint, 
                                           target::bigint, cost_s::double precision as cost, 
                                           reverse_cost_s::double precision as reverse_cost FROM ways 
                                           WHERE the_geom && ST_Expand((SELECT ST_Collect(the_geom) 
                                           FROM ways_vertices_pgr WHERE id IN(589143, 581050)), 0.01)', 
589143, 581050) a LEFT JOIN ways b ON (a.edge = b.gid);
```

But when I use the same query in Node Js (see below), I get an error message saying `error: syntax error at or near "&&"`. What am I doing wrong?

```
const start = parseInt(request.params.start)
const end = parseInt(request.params.end)

const sql2 = 
     "SELECT b.gid, b.the_geom, b.cost_s, b.length_m FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid::bigint as id, source::bigint,"+
     "target::bigint, cost_s::double precision as cost," +
     "reverse_cost_s::double precision as reverse_cost FROM ways" + 
     "WHERE the_geom && ST_Expand((SELECT ST_Collect(the_geom)" + 
     "FROM ways_vertices_pgr WHERE id IN(" + start + "," + end + ")), 0.01)'," +
      start + "," + end + ") a LEFT JOIN ways b ON (a.edge = b.gid);"
```

Comment: You possibly need an extra space after `FROM ways" +`.

Comment: Also on a side note, it might not be a good idea to pass concatenated string to the SQL engine. Have a look at how to create `prepared statements` in postgres to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: What do you mean with extra space after `FROM ways" +`?

Comment: Maybe somthing like `"FROM ways " +`.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Instead of `start` and `end` I used arguments using the syntax `$1`...and added the data type of the arguments. In  my case `ineteger`

```
SELECT b.gid, b.the_geom, b.cost_s, b.length_m FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid::bigint as id, source::bigint, 
                                           target::bigint, cost_s::double precision as cost, 
                                           reverse_cost_s::double precision as reverse_cost FROM ways 
                                           WHERE the_geom && ST_Expand((SELECT ST_Collect(the_geom) 
                                           FROM ways_vertices_pgr WHERE id IN(' || $1::integer || ',' || $2::integer ||')), 0.01)', 
    $1::integer, $2::integer) a LEFT JOIN ways b ON (a.edge = b.gid);
```